# count: int = len(data_from_postgres) TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, django

count: int = len(data_from_postgres) TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
There is such an error

```
   data_from_postgres = query_postgres(state_file=state_file, query=query)
   count: int = len(data_from_postgres)
   index: int = 0
   actions: list = []
   while count != 0:
```

Comment: perhaps the query returned `None` or an error?

Comment: Print `data_from_postgres` or use one of the instance's methods to inspect the size. Expect that queries will return no results and check before using them with something like `if not data_from_postgres: # raise error` or explicitly check the emptiness if the queryset doesn't implement `__bool__()`.